# PHP - looping in 3 dimentional array gives wired output

Tags: php, loops, foreach

While looping, 3rd loop is not giving correct output. 
3rd loop should get all matched name from 2nd array loop. 
But it is getting only first array item from second array, and ignoring all other array items.

Which can be possible explanation here? Is there any problem in code?

```
<?php
$t = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mshafrir/2646763/raw/8b0dbb93521f5d6889502305335104218454c2bf/states_titlecase.json'), true);

$reg_state_short = array();

$reg_state = array(
    array('Connecticut',' Maine',' Massachusetts',' New Hampshire',' Rhode Island',' Vermont'), 
    array('New Jersey',' New York',' Puerto Rico',' US Virgin Islands'), 
    array('Delaware',' District of Columbia',' Maryland',' Pennsylvania',' Virginia',' West Virginia'), 
    array('Alabama',' Florida',' Georgia',' Kentucky',' Mississippi',' North Carolina',' South Carolina',' Tennessee'), 
    array('Illinois',' Indiana',' Michigan',' Minnesota',' Ohio',' Wisconsin'), 
    array('Arkansas',' Louisiana',' New Mexico',' Oklahoma',' Texas'), 
    array('Iowa',' Kansas',' Missouri',' Nebraska'), 
    array('Colorado',' Montana',' North Dakota',' South Dakota',' Utah',' Wyoming'), 
    array('Arizona',' California',' Hawaii',' Nevada',' American Samoa',' Guam',' Northern Mariana Islands'), 
    array('Alaska',' Idaho',' Oregon',' Washington')
);

foreach ($reg_state as $reg_state2) {
    foreach ($reg_state2 as $state) {
        foreach ($t as $t2) {         
            if ($t2['name'] === $state ) {
                $reg_state_short[] = $t2['abbreviation'];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r($reg_state_short);
```

Comment: what is the desired output you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra space in the left side in some states in your `$reg_state`

For example:

```
' Maine'
```

Should be:

```
'Maine'
```

Here's the full code:

```
$t = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mshafrir/2646763/raw/8b0dbb93521f5d6889502305335104218454c2bf/states_titlecase.json'), true);

$reg_state_short = array();

$reg_state = array(
    array('Connecticut','Maine','Massachusetts','New Hampshire','Rhode Island','Vermont'), 
    array('New Jersey','New York','Puerto Rico','US Virgin Islands'), 
    array('Delaware','District of Columbia','Maryland','Pennsylvania','Virginia','West Virginia'), 
    array('Alabama','Florida','Georgia','Kentucky','Mississippi','North Carolina','South Carolina','Tennessee'), 
    array('Illinois','Indiana','Michigan','Minnesota','Ohio','Wisconsin'), 
    array('Arkansas','Louisiana','New Mexico','Oklahoma','Texas'), 
    array('Iowa','Kansas','Missouri','Nebraska'), 
    array('Colorado','Montana','North Dakota','South Dakota','Utah','Wyoming'), 
    array('Arizona','California','Hawaii','Nevada','American Samoa','Guam','Northern Mariana Islands'), 
    array('Alaska','Idaho','Oregon','Washington')
);

foreach ($reg_state as $reg_state2) {
    foreach ($reg_state2 as $state) {
        foreach ($t as $t2) {         
            if ($t2['name'] === $state ) {
                $reg_state_short[] = $t2['abbreviation'];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r($reg_state_short);
```

Comment: Yah, whitespace was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I compared all array values using the following code. I hope this could help you:

```
$t = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mshafrir/2646763/raw/8b0dbb93521f5d6889502305335104218454c2bf/states_titlecase.json'), true);
    $t_array = array();
    foreach($t as $k => $row){
        array_push($t_array, $row['name']); 
    }

    $reg_state = array(
        array('Connecticut',' Maine',' Massachusetts',' New Hampshire',' Rhode Island',' Vermont'), 
        array('New Jersey',' New York',' Puerto Rico',' US Virgin Islands'), 
        array('Delaware',' District of Columbia',' Maryland',' Pennsylvania',' Virginia',' West Virginia'), 
        array('Alabama',' Florida',' Georgia',' Kentucky',' Mississippi',' North Carolina',' South Carolina',' Tennessee'), 
        array('Illinois',' Indiana',' Michigan',' Minnesota',' Ohio',' Wisconsin'), 
        array('Arkansas',' Louisiana',' New Mexico',' Oklahoma',' Texas'), 
        array('Iowa',' Kansas',' Missouri',' Nebraska'), 
        array('Colorado',' Montana',' North Dakota',' South Dakota',' Utah',' Wyoming'), 
        array('Arizona',' California',' Hawaii',' Nevada',' American Samoa',' Guam',' Northern Mariana Islands'), 
        array('Alaska',' Idaho',' Oregon',' Washington')
    );  

    $reg_state_short = array();
    foreach($reg_state as $k => $row){
        foreach($row as $k2 => $row2){
            if(in_array($row2, $t_array)){
                array_push($reg_state_short, $row2);
            }
        }
    }

    print_r($reg_state_short);
```

Comment: nah, same problem. 
It is just getting first array element from second array. 
Same problem with my code

Comment: Problem was with whitespeace like evilReiko said

Answer (score 0):

Just trim leading and trailing space

you have leading spaces in `$reg_state`, for example `' Maine',' Massachusetts'`

```
foreach ($reg_state as $reg_state2) {
    foreach ($reg_state2 as $state) {
        foreach ($t as $t2) {         
            if (trim($t2['name']) === trim($state) ) {
                $reg_state_short[] = $t2['abbreviation'];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r($reg_state_short);
```

What I have done is trim leading and trailing space using `trim` in `if` statement
`trim($t2['name']) === trim($state)`

Comment: Yes, problem was the whitespeace like evilReiko said